# Can I make a dialog appear to ask what to do when I insert a DVD?

Tags: release-freya

In Ubuntu, I have the option - in Settings/Details - to configure what applications and actions to use/do when a DVD is inserted.
Although libdvdread4 is installed in my client's Freya OS, I couldn't find the Settings/Details dialog.
I want to be able to set up her Freya in regards to applications/actions when a DVD is inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimatelly, what I need is that whenever a DVD is inserted Frey asks what to do or automatically start a specific application.
And it seems that Freya actually lacks that functionality, according to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1211118).
So, for now, it seems that the answer to my question is... "No, you can't".